# Hoverfly does not intercept my own defined host in destination

Tags: hoverfly

When I start hoverfly in simulate mode (or as a webserver, it doesn't matter) and define some *destination* then I must do request via proxy (or straight to localhost:8500 in case of webserver).

Is there a way to start hoverfly and define *destination*, for example as "my-host" so that I could do requests straight to *http://my-host/some-path* instead of using proxy or localhost:8500?

P.S. this way works in integration tests when I use **hoverfly-java** but doesn't work via CLI

Answer (score 0):

Hoverfly is bind to loopback interface by default, meaning that you can only access to it on localhost. To access it remotely, you can specify the IP address it listens on. For example, setting 0.0.0.0 to listen on all network interfaces. [[Source]](https://hoverfly.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/troubleshooting/troubleshooting.html#why-am-i-not-able-to-access-my-hoverfly-remotely)

Try: 
hoverctl start --listen-on-host 0.0.0.0 webserver

So if your "my-host" ip is 10.10.10.136. Then your requests would look like
http://10.10.10.136:8500/some-path